# Couldn't start exited docker container after restart of host machine

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I unexpectedly shut down my host machine and when turned it on again all my docker containers became exited.

I can see them using `docker ps -a`

I cant start any of them using `docker start {container_id}`

I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container cc61efa31df8: [8] System error: not a directory
Error: failed to start containers: [cc61efa31df8]
```

Has anyone ever tried to start exited container?

I don't want to remove and recreate containers because I have some data on mysql container.

I'm on Mac, using parallels driver for docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @Thanh Nguyen Van's answer helped me to understand the problem I'm not marking it as a correct one because it seems initial problem stays unresolved.

I used [docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) and located database volumes.

I checked them and they where empty, which makes me think that volumes where destroyed/deleted after shutdown and this is correct according to [boot2docker documentation](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#persist-data).

> Changes outside of these directories will be lost after powering down
>   or restarting the VM - to make permanent modifications see the [FAQ](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition).

So there is nothing wrong.

If anyone wants to persist data between restarts of docker-machine just make sure that you map database files to your host machine, so newly started docker-machine will mount your mapped folders as a container volume.

Answer (score 1):

View logs of container to find out what is error.

```
> docker logs cc61efa31df8
```

I guess your docker container contain mysql service. so mysql service counldnot start when you start docker container.